# MvvmCross - View Model mvxInteraction is always null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to MvvmCross and Xamarin, maybe I miss something here but when I trying to pass some data from `ViewModel` to `View` like it's described here (almost)

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/mvxinteraction

But the thing is - my `MvxInteraction` variable in `View` is always null, even though I pass there string!

```
   public IMvxInteraction<MenuViewModel.YesNoQuestion> Interaction
        {
            get
            {
                return _interaction;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_interaction != null) // <-- Always NULL!
                    _interaction.Requested -= OnInteractionRequested;

                _interaction = value;
                _interaction.Requested += OnInteractionRequested;
            }
        }
```

ViewModel code:

```
  public class MenuViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private IDataScanner _dataScanner { get; set; }

        //demo
        public class YesNoQuestion
        {
            public string Question { get; set; }
        }

        private MvxInteraction<YesNoQuestion> _interaction = new MvxInteraction<YesNoQuestion>();
        // need to expose it as a public property for binding (only IMvxInteraction is needed in the view)
        public IMvxInteraction<YesNoQuestion> Interaction
        {
            get
            {
                return _interaction;
            }
        }


        private void DoFinishProfileCommand()
        {
            // 1. do cool stuff with profile data
            // ...

            // 2. request interaction from view
            // 3. execution continues in callbacks
            var request = new YesNoQuestion
            {
                Question = "Do you want to save your profile?"
            };

            _interaction.Raise(request);
        }
        // demo

        public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public List<string> DataList;
        }

        public delegate void ScanDoneEvent(object sender, DataEventArgs args);
        public event ScanDoneEvent ScanDone;

        protected virtual void OnScanDone(List<string> dataList)
        {
            ScanDone?.Invoke(this, new DataEventArgs { DataList = dataList });
        }

        public MenuViewModel(IDataScanner dataScanner)
        {
            _dataScanner = dataScanner;

            RunScan();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _filesCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<string> FilesCollection
        {
            get { return _filesCollection; }
            set
            {
                _filesCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FilesCollection);
            }
        }

        private async void RunScan()
        {
            var files = await _dataScanner.GetDataListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            FilesCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
            DoFinishProfileCommand();
        }

    }
```

View code:

```
  [Activity]
    public class MenuView : MvxActivity
    {
        public MenuView()
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MenuView, MenuViewModel>();
            set.Bind(this).For(view => view.Interaction).To(viewModel => viewModel.Interaction).OneWay();
            set.Apply();
        }
        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.menu_view);
        }

        //demo
        private IMvxInteraction<MenuViewModel.YesNoQuestion> _interaction;
        public IMvxInteraction<MenuViewModel.YesNoQuestion> Interaction
        {
            get
            {
                return _interaction;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_interaction != null)// <-- Always NULL!
                    _interaction.Requested -= OnInteractionRequested;

                _interaction = value;
                _interaction.Requested += OnInteractionRequested;
            }
        }

        private async void OnInteractionRequested(object sender, MvxValueEventArgs<MenuViewModel.YesNoQuestion> eventArgs)
        {
            var yesNoQuestion = eventArgs.Value.Question;
            // show dialog
            Toast.MakeText(this, yesNoQuestion, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }


    }
```

**UPD 09.11.2017**

Finally make it work in the way I wanted to.

Instead of MvxInteraction I just simply used service, as [nmilcoff](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5000213/nmilcoff) (thanks much for the answer btw) advised, and when I called toast from it wrap it in `runOnUiThread`.

So, final code is here.

ToastService:

```
public class ToastService : IToastService
    {
        private readonly IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity _topActivity;

        public ToastService(IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity topActivity)
        {
            _topActivity = topActivity;
        }

        public void ShowToast(string message)
        {
            _topActivity.Activity.RunOnUiThread(
                () => Toast.MakeText(_topActivity.Activity.ApplicationContext, message, ToastLength.Long).Show()
            );
        }
    }
```

MenuViewModel:

```
 public class MenuViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private IDataScanner _dataScanner { get; set; }
        private IToastService _toastService { get; set; }

        public MenuViewModel(IDataScanner dataScanner, IToastService toastService)
        {
            _dataScanner = dataScanner;
            _toastService = toastService;
        }

        public override void ViewAppeared()
        {
            base.ViewAppeared();
            RunScan();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _filesCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<string> FilesCollection
        {
            get { return _filesCollection; }
            set
            {
                _filesCollection = value;
               // RaisePropertyChanged(() => FilesCollection);

            }
        }

        private async void RunScan()
        {
            var files = await _dataScanner.GetDataListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            FilesCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
            //  Someval = files[0];
           _toastService.ShowToast(files[0]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the [StarWarsSample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/StarWarsSample) interesting, as it uses [MvxInteraction](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/StarWarsSample/StarWarsSample.Droid/Views/PlanetView.cs#L33).

As you can see in that app, you need to declare the bindings later in your View code. Can you move the Fluent Binding block to the Activity's `OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)` method? Something like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MenuView, MenuViewModel>();
    set.Bind(this).For(view => view.Interaction).To(viewModel => viewModel.Interaction).OneWay();
    set.Apply();
}
```

But that probably won't work because you're requesting the MvxInteraction too soon in your code. Therefore I recommend you to use a Dependency Service instead:

1) Create an interface at Core level with a method that displays a toast:

```
public interface IToastService
{
    void ShowToast(string message);
}
```

2) Create an implementation of the service at platform level:

```
public class ToastService : IToastService
{
    private readonly IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity _topActivity;

    public ToastService(IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity topActivity)
    {
        _topActivity = topActivity;
    }

    public void ShowToast(string message)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(activity.ApplicationContext, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

3) Register your service with the IoC Container. Something like this (inside the Setup class of your platform project):

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
        base.InitializeLastChance();

        Mvx.RegisterType<IToastService, ToastService>();
}
```

That's it. You're ready to inject/resolve your IToastService wherever you want!

Comment: oh, now it's not null, but OnIteractionRequested is not even toggled ._.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside OnInteractionRequested it's not hit? Otherwise, if the debugger steps into the method, make sure the phone's keyboard is not displayed, as Toasts are normally shown behind it.

Comment: It not even hits the method, that's the problem

Comment: I just noticed you're requiesting the MvxInteraction too soon on your code. Bindings are not set at that moment. I can think of two alternatives: (1) Move your `RunScan` call to a method like `ViewAppearing` (if you're using MvvmCross 5+... otherwise `Start`). | (2) Use a dependency service instead: Declare an interface with a method to show a toast at Core level and the implementation at a platform level.

Comment: So, I can call things like `Toast` or something like this from simple services? I tought only in case of Activity it's possible )

Comment: Also, put `RunScan` into `Start` method didn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158513/discussion-between-danil-gholtsman-and-nmilcoff).

Comment: oh thx! but there is error now,I tried this service approach and disabled `MvxIteraction` part https://i.gyazo.com/b32dec0f19e7cb8cb4586bd2ce2a439c.png