# WPF InteractionRequest is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross, user-interaction

Hi I'm new to WPF and XAML, I'm trying to utilize MVVMCross's MvxInteraction to interact with the user to get a "YES" or "NO" confirmation based off this [example](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/mvxinteraction).

I've been hitting a snag on getting the interaction to subscribe to an event handler as the interaction is always null. I can see that from the references that the interaction variable see each other based on the binding, so I'm not sure what's going on. I've looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074979/mvvmcross-view-model-mvxinteraction-is-always-null/47171294), that states for me to bring my binding later into my UserControl View behind code, so I used a dispatcher, but that did not work either.

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class StudentDetailsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private InteractionRequest<YesNoQuestion> _interaction = new InteractionRequest<YesNoQuestion>();

    public IInteractionRequest Interaction => _interaction;
 }
```

**VIEW.XAML.CS**

```
public partial class StudentDetailsView : MvxWpfView
{
    private InteractionRequest<YesNoQuestion> _interaction;

    public StudentDetailsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => BindInteractions()), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
    }

    public InteractionRequest<YesNoQuestion> Interaction
    {
        get => _interaction;
        set
        {
            if(_interaction != null)
            {
                _interaction.Requested -= OnInteractionRequested;
            }

            _interaction = value;
            _interaction.Requested += OnInteractionRequested; //***RUN TIME NULL EXCEPTION***
        }
    }

    private void OnInteractionRequested(object sender, InteractionRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var yesNoQuestion = eventArgs.Callback;
    }

    private void BindInteractions()
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<StudentDetailsView, StudentDetailsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(this).For(view => view.Interaction).To(viewModel => viewModel.Interaction).OneWay();
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

**INTERACTION CLASS**

```
public class YesNoQuestion
{
    public bool? Confirmation { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public YesNoQuestion(string message)
    {
        Question = message;
    }
}
```

My second question is that I'm a little confused on what they implemented with the "ShowDialog" and "DialogStatus" here within their example:

```
private async void OnInteractionRequested(object sender, MvxValueEventArgs<YesNoQuestion> eventArgs)
{
    var yesNoQuestion = eventArgs.Value;
    // show dialog
    var status = await ShowDialog(yesNoQuestion.Question);
    yesNoQuestion.YesNoCallback(status == DialogStatus.Yes);
}
```

Are they simply calling upon another usercontrol view to show itself through a ShowDialog Method?

Answer (score 1):

```
_interaction.Requested += OnInteractionRequested; //***RUN TIME NULL EXCEPTION***
```

Somehow this is always null on the first startup, and then it will assign the proper interaction later, so add a null check to solve this. Maybe we need to confirm with MVVMCross itself.

Second, you can handle whatever you want to display on interaction request, for example, shows MessageBox with yes no button type or pop another view to display custom message box one. Since this runs on the WPF layer.